Problem creating and decoding jwttokens with Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
I want to create a jwttoken with some claims.
Afterward I want to verify this token and get a ClaimsPrincipal object.
I use the following libraries:
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

Here is the code that generates my token
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AuthSettings.PrivateKey);
var credentials = new SigningCredentials(
    new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Username),
    new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, user.ID.ToString()),
    new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, user.ID.ToString()), 
    new(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.ID.ToString()), 
    new(ClaimTypes.Role, user.UserPermitionLevel.ToString()),

};
var identity = new GenericIdentity(user.Username);
var claimsidentity = new ClaimsIdentity(identity, claims);
DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(AuthSettings.ExpiryMinutes).ToString())
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = claimsidentity, 
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(AuthSettings.ExpiryMinutes),
    SigningCredentials = credentials,
};

var token = handler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
var tk = handler.WriteToken(token);

var res1 = handler.ReadJwtToken(tk);
var res2 = handler.ReadToken(tk);

return handler.WriteToken(token);

The generated token is:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Ik1GSSIsInN1YiI6Ik1GSSIsImp0aSI6IjEiLCJuYW1laWQiOlsiMSIsIjEiXSwicm9sZSI6IkFkbWluIiwibmJmIjoxNzI2MjEwOTA5LCJleHAiOjE3MjYyMTI3MDksImlhdCI6MTcyNjIxMDkwOX0.GHTv_n6W4M6qftQ2myv8vvLg8AqvUf40dG2e5_pZBlo

The payload of it is:
{
  "unique_name": "MFI",
  "sub": "MFI",
  "jti": "1",
  "nameid": [
    "1",
    "1"
  ],
  "role": "Admin",
  "nbf": 1726210909,
  "exp": 1726212709,
  "iat": 1726210909
}

That looks good so fare.
When I now read this token with handler.ReadToken(tk) or with handler.ReadJwtToken(tk) the payload only contains 4 elements.

The Claims also only contain the same 4 elements.
I don't see where I am wrong.
I googled extensively and used chat-gpt but wars not able to solve the problem on my own.
Can you please help me?

I had a test within my side with your codes and everything worked well. I can't reproduce your issue, my payload count is 8. https://i.sstatic.net/FyFWkAuV.png

Thank you for your help. Now I put this code into a blank ASP.NET API and came to the same result as you did. Al Claims where present in res1 and res2. Now I need to find where I brok my original application so that it does not longer work.

I found my problem. In my application I used old NuGet-libraries. I updated the libraries "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" and "Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" from 7.1.2 to 8.0.8 and it worked.

Thank you for your sharing @Martin Could you pls update your finding in the answer to end this question?

The Code in this question wars correct.
After @Tiny Wang commented on my question, I created a new dummy Project with the same code and it worked just fine.
The difference between the two applications was that in my application I used old versions of NuGet-libraries "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" and "Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens".
After I updated the libraries from 7.1.2 to 8.0.8 and it worked as expected.
